# Multiple glibc libraries on a single host

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc

My linux (SLES-8) server currently has glibc-2.2.5-235, but I have a program which won't work on this version and requires glibc-2.3.3.

Is it possible to have multiple glibcs installed on the same host?

This is the error I get when I run my program on the old glibc:

```
./myapp: /lib/i686/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.3' not found (required by ./myapp)
./myapp: /lib/i686/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.3.2' not found (required by ./myapp)
./myapp: /lib/i686/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.3' not found (required by ./libxerces-c.so.27)
./myapp: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: version `GLIBC_2.3' not found (required by ./libstdc++.so.6)
./myapp: /lib/i686/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.3' not found (required by ./libstdc++.so.6)
```

So I created a new directory called newglibc and copied the following files in:

```
libpthread.so.0
libm.so.6
libc.so.6
ld-2.3.3.so
ld-linux.so.2 -> ld-2.3.3.so
```

and

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=newglibc:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

But I get an error:

```
./myapp: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: version `GLIBC_PRIVATE' not found (required by ./newglibc/libpthread.so.0)
./myapp: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: version `GLIBC_2.3' not found (required by libstdc++.so.6)
./myapp: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: version `GLIBC_PRIVATE' not found (required by ./newglibc/libm.so.6)
./myapp: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: version `GLIBC_2.3' not found (required by ./newglibc/libc.so.6)
./myapp: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: version `GLIBC_PRIVATE' not found (required by ./newglibc/libc.so.6)
```

So it appears that they are still linking to `/lib` and not picking up from where I put them.

Comment: same issue with SLES-11 server. Can't update and need recent stuff. oh my...

Comment: FWIW, `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=newglibc:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` *did* solve the problem for me!  It certainly wont' work for everyone, but it's an easy fix if it does work!  Thanks! :)

Comment: You only need one glibc version: the highest that is required. It shall be retro-compatible.

Comment: @AlbertoSalviaNovella except it is not https://maskray.me/blog/2022-08-21-glibc-and-dt-gnu-hash

Comment: @Rainb That was an special case where they deprecated a function which was been replaced like 15 years ago.

Answer (score 325, accepted):

It is very possible to have multiple versions of glibc on the same system (we do that every day).

However, you need to know that glibc consists of many pieces (200+ shared libraries) which all must match. One of the pieces is ld-linux.so.2, and it *must* match libc.so.6, or you'll see the errors you are seeing.

The absolute path to ld-linux.so.2 is hard-coded into the executable at link time, and can not be easily changed after the link is done (Update: can be done with  [patchelf](http://nixos.org/patchelf.html); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44710599/50617) below).

To build an executable that will work with the new glibc, do this:

```
g++ main.o -o myapp ... \
   -Wl,--rpath=/path/to/newglibc \
   -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/path/to/newglibc/ld-linux.so.2
```

The `-rpath` linker option will make the runtime loader search for libraries in `/path/to/newglibc` (so you wouldn't have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before running it), and the `-dynamic-linker` option will "bake" path to correct `ld-linux.so.2` into the application.

If you can't relink the `myapp` application (e.g. because it is a third-party binary), not all is lost, but it gets trickier. One solution is to set a proper `chroot` environment for it. Another possibility is to use [rtldi](http://bitwagon.com/rtldi/rtldi.html) and a [binary editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_editor).

**Update:** or you can use [patchelf](http://nixos.org/patchelf.html) on existing binaries to redirect them to the alternate libc.

Comment: Now you can use a convenient utility `patchelf` (http://nixos.org/patchelf.html), which allows you to modify rpath and interpreter of already compiled ELF.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that specifying the path to the new glibc using `-Wl,--rpath` rather than `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` can be important for reasons other than convenience: if the program launches child processes, the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will usually be inherited by them, but if they're not also compiled to use the newer glibc (for example, if they're stock binaries like `bash`), they won't launch.

Comment: Another option is running the new ld.so directly, passing it your binary program as a parameter; this will effectively replace ld.so used w/o the need to recompile the program:
`/path/to/newglibc/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path /path/tonewglibc/lib64:/path/to/newglibc/usr/lib64 /path/to/myapp`

Comment: I also needed `-I` and `-L`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52454603/895245

Comment: How to download and use the glibc? Should I download the RPM and extract it or should built it locally? I am getting hard time to these questions

Comment: @SantoshKale To install in "parallel" location, you must `configure --prefix /new/location` and `make && make install`. Prebuilt RPM will not work.

Comment: @HighCommander4 can you explain why a child process would not launch? Does a child process use libraries loaded by its parent? Wouldn't it work anyway with newer glibc too?

Comment: @lumbric It's not the libraries that are inherited from the parent, but the environment variables (to be precise, they *may* be, depending on how the child process is launched), in which case the child process would look in the same `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You're right that if the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` just points to newer versions of backward-compatible libraries like libc, that should still work. (I suspect I wrote the comment because I ran into a situation where it didn't work, but unfortunately I don't remember the details.)

Comment: @HighCommander4 Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to newer `libc` does _not_ work, and the reason is explained in the answer above. `libc` is _not_ backward compatible if you don't change `ld-linux` to match.

Answer (score 147):

This question is old, the other answers are old. [Employed Russian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/) is very good and informative, but it only works if you have the source code. If you don't, the alternatives back then were very tricky. Fortunately nowadays we have a simple solution to this problem (as commented in [one of his replies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host#comment20817799_851229)), using [patchelf](http://nixos.org/patchelf.html). All you have to do is:

```
$ ./patchelf --set-interpreter /path/to/newglibc/ld-linux.so.2 --set-rpath /path/to/newglibc/ myapp
```

This changes the non-working executable to use a different path for its linker. And after that, you can just execute your file:

```
$ ./myapp
```

No need to `chroot` or manually edit binaries, thankfully. But remember to backup your binary before patching it, if you're not sure what you're doing, because it modifies your binary file. After you patch it, you can't restore the old path to interpreter/rpath. If it doesn't work, you'll have to keep patching it until you find the path that will actually work... Well, it doesn't have to be a trial-and-error process. For example, in OP's example, he needed `GLIBC_2.3`, so you can easily find which lib provides that version using `strings`:

```
$ strings /lib/i686/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC_2.3
$ strings /path/to/newglib/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC_2.3
```

In theory, the first grep would come empty because the system libc doesn't have the version he wants, and the 2nd one should output GLIBC_2.3 because it has the version `myapp` is using, so we know we can `patchelf` our binary using that path. If you get a segmentation fault, read the note at the end.

When you try to run a binary in linux, the binary tries to load the linker (aka loader, aka interpreter), then the libraries, and they should all be in the path and/or in the right place. If your problem is with the linker and you want to find out which path your binary is looking for, you can find out with this command:

```
$ readelf -l myapp | grep interpreter
  [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]
```

If your problem is with the libs, commands that will give you the libs being used are:

```
$ readelf -d myapp | grep Shared
$ ldd myapp
```

This will list the libs that your binary needs, but you probably already know the problematic ones, since they are already yielding errors as in OP's case. After you do patchelf, it might happen that `myapp` is still not working, and when you run `ldd myapp` it lists the libs with mixed paths, some to the path you set, others to the original system path. That's because your path doesn't have those libs. `rpath` will search for the lib in the path you set, but if it's not there, it still looks for it in the other system locations. In this case, if you have the missing lib somewhere, just copy it to the `rpath` that you chose and it should work.

"patchelf" works for many different problems that you may encounter while trying to run a program, related to these 2 problems. For example, if you get: `ELF file OS ABI invalid`, it may be fixed by setting a new loader (the `--set-interpreter` part of the command) as I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48654678/2193235). Another example is for the problem of getting `No such file or directory` when you run a file that is there and executable, as exemplified [here](https://superuser.com/questions/248512/why-do-i-get-command-not-found-when-the-binary-file-exists). In that particular case, OP was missing a link to the loader, but maybe in your case you don't have root access and can't create the link. Setting a new interpreter would solve your problem.

Thanks Employed Russian and Michael Pankov for the insight and solution!

---

*Note* for segmentation fault: you might be in the case where `myapp` uses several libs, and most of them are ok but some are not; then you `patchelf` it to a new dir, and you get segmentation fault. When you `patchelf` your binary, you change the path of several libs, even if some were originally in a different path. Take a look at my example below:

```
$ ldd myapp
./myapp: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./myapp)
./myapp: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./myapp)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffb167c000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9a9aad2000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9a9a8ce000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9a9a6af000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9a9a3ab000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9a99fe6000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9a9adeb000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9a99dcf000)
```

Note that most libs are in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` but the problematic one (`libstdc++.so.6`) is on `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. After I patchelf'ed `myapp` to point to `/path/to/mylibs`, I got segmentation fault. For some reason, the libs are not totally compatible with the binary. Since `myapp` didn't complain about the original libs, I copied them from `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` to `/path/to/mylibs2`, and I also copied `libstdc++.so.6` from `/path/to/mylibs` there. Then I patchelf'ed it to `/path/to/mylibs2`, and `myapp` works now. If your binary uses different libs, and you have different versions, it might happen that you can't fix your situation. :( But if it's possible, mixing libs might be the way. It's not ideal, but *maybe* it will work. Good luck!

Comment: Really helpful utility! Thank you! Although I only managed to obtain a segmentation fault after hours of manually resolving dependencies then patching everything to locally install chrome with no admin privileges...

Comment: @fgiraldeau thanks for the compliment. :) but the question was asked, answered and accepted in 2009, I wouldn't expect someone to wait 8 years before accepting an answer. heheh ;D

Comment: hi, ironically i get `./patchelf: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./patchelf)` I think I gonna check for another solution

Comment: The patchelf page points to the source code, at https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf so in theory you could compile it in your system... but that might bring its own set of problems. lol :(

Comment: @Welgriv you need to do that on the computer that you compiled both patchelf and your app. Later this transfer to other computer.

Comment: I tried to patchelf libc-2.17.so as above, but I am still getting relocation error: libc.so.6: symbol _dl_starting_up, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference

Comment: @AlexO You're not supposed to patch libc, you're supposed to patch the executable that uses libc (by pointing it to a different libc that has the version you need). Maybe post a new question here in StackOverflow with all the details of your problem and what you tried. :)

Comment: When using perl, I face the `GLIBC_2.28' not found issue, and patchelf solution can help me to pass it. But after that, I face another issue Cwd.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched.

Comment: see this answer for how to install glibc in a temp location so that it doesn't interfere with system libraries https://askubuntu.com/a/1345783/176104

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a bug, or an expected behavior due to something very subtle, but I've some across an example where using `patchelf` with `--set-interpreter` and `--set-rpath` in a single step seems to corrupt the executable. To preserve its integrity, I have to do it in two separate steps, and in a specific order (`--set-rpath` first, followed by `--set-interpreter`). See https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf/issues/524

Answer (score 21):

Use LD_PRELOAD:
put your library somewhere out of the man lib directories and run:

```
LD_PRELOAD='mylibc.so anotherlib.so' program
```

See: [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker)

Comment: thought this would be a nice workaround for a complex Makefile, but it didn't work for me

Comment: that's useful particularly those no source binary.thanks

Comment: um...i was wrong,,it seem like i need rpath the ld-linux.so to /path/to/new/lib/ frist while source compile & linking

Comment: This doesn't work if ld-#.##.so (from your system glibc lib) isn't the same glibc version as libc.so.# (from your alternate glibc lib)

Answer (score 18):

First of all, the most important dependency of each dynamically linked program is the linker. All so libraries must match the version of the linker.

Let's take simple exaple: I have the newset ubuntu system where I run some program (in my case it is D compiler - ldc2). I'd like to run it on the old CentOS, but because of the older glibc library it is impossible. I got

```
ldc2-1.5.0-linux-x86_64/bin/ldc2: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by ldc2-1.5.0-linux-x86_64/bin/ldc2)
ldc2-1.5.0-linux-x86_64/bin/ldc2: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ldc2-1.5.0-linux-x86_64/bin/ldc2)
```

I have to copy all dependencies from ubuntu to centos.
The proper method is following:

First, let's check all dependencies:

```
ldd ldc2-1.5.0-linux-x86_64/bin/ldc2 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffebad3f000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f965f597000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f965f378000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f965f15b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f965ef57000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f965ec01000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f965e9ea000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f965e60a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f965f79f000)
```

linux-vdso.so.1 is not a real library and we don't have to care about it.

/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 is the linker, which is used by the linux do link the executable with all dynamic libraries.

Rest of the files are real libraries and all of them together with the linker must be copied somewhere in the centos.

Let's assume all the libraries and linker are in "/mylibs" directory.

ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 - as I've already said - is the linker. It's not dynamic library but static executable. You can run it and see that it even have some parameters, eg --library-path (I'll return to it).

On the linux, dynamically linked program may be lunched just by its name, eg

```
/bin/ldc2
```

Linux loads such program into RAM, and checks which linker is set for it. Usually, on 64-bit system, it is /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (in your filesystem it is symbolic link to the real executable).
Then linux runs the linker and it loads dynamic libraries.

You can also change this a little and do such trick:

```
/mylibs/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /bin/ldc2
```

It is the method for forcing the linux to use specific linker.

And now we can return to the mentioned earlier parameter --library-path

```
/mylibs/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /mylibs /bin/ldc2
```

It will run ldc2 and load dynamic libraries from /mylibs.

This is the method to call the executable with choosen (not system default) libraries.

Comment: I compiled a program on RH7 and need it to run on RH6.  I didn't want to build a new executable or use patchelf, so this is a great alternative.

Comment: Trying to use this approach to compile mongo db v4 with custom gcc 5.3 on debian jessie but getting a segmentation fault running linker directly here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65256105/dynamic-linker-direct-call-segmentation-fault-when-running-an-app-compiled-whith could you help?

Answer (score 16):

### Setup 1: compile your own glibc without dedicated GCC and use it

This setup might work and is quick as it does not recompile the whole GCC toolchain, just glibc.

But it is not reliable as it uses host C runtime objects such as `crt1.o`, `crti.o`, and `crtn.o` provided by glibc. This is mentioned at: https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds?action=recall&rev=21#Compile_against_glibc_in_an_installed_location Those objects do early setup that glibc relies on, so I wouldn't be surprised if things crashed in wonderful and awesomely subtle ways.

For a more reliable setup, see Setup 2 below.

Build glibc and install locally:

```
export glibc_install="$(pwd)/glibc/build/install"

git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git
cd glibc
git checkout glibc-2.28
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix "$glibc_install"
make -j `nproc`
make install -j `nproc`
```

#### Setup 1: verify the build

test_glibc.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <assert.h>
#include <gnu/libc-version.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <threads.h>

atomic_int acnt;
int cnt;

int f(void* thr_data) {
    for(int n = 0; n < 1000; ++n) {
        ++cnt;
        ++acnt;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* Basic library version check. */
    printf("gnu_get_libc_version() = %s\n", gnu_get_libc_version());

    /* Exercise thrd_create from -pthread,
     * which is not present in glibc 2.27 in Ubuntu 18.04.
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810/how-do-i-start-threads-in-plain-c/52453291#52453291 */
    thrd_t thr[10];
    for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
        thrd_create(&thr[n], f, NULL);
    for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
        thrd_join(thr[n], NULL);
    printf("The atomic counter is %u\n", acnt);
    printf("The non-atomic counter is %u\n", cnt);
}
```

Compile and run with `test_glibc.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eux
gcc \
  -L "${glibc_install}/lib" \
  -I "${glibc_install}/include" \
  -Wl,--rpath="${glibc_install}/lib" \
  -Wl,--dynamic-linker="${glibc_install}/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" \
  -std=c11 \
  -o test_glibc.out \
  -v \
  test_glibc.c \
  -pthread \
;
ldd ./test_glibc.out
./test_glibc.out
```

The program outputs the expected:

```
gnu_get_libc_version() = 2.28
The atomic counter is 10000
The non-atomic counter is 8674
```

Command adapted from https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds?action=recall&rev=21#Compile_against_glibc_in_an_installed_location but `--sysroot` made it fail with:

```
cannot find /home/ciro/glibc/build/install/lib/libc.so.6 inside /home/ciro/glibc/build/install
```

so I removed it.

`ldd` output confirms that the `ldd` and libraries that we've just built are actually being used as expected:

```
+ ldd test_glibc.out
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe4bfd3000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /home/ciro/glibc/build/install/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc12ed92000)
        libc.so.6 => /home/ciro/glibc/build/install/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc12e9dc000)
        /home/ciro/glibc/build/install/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc12f1b3000)
```

The `gcc` compilation debug output shows that my host runtime objects were used, which is bad as mentioned previously, but I don't know how to work around it, e.g. it contains:

```
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
```

#### Setup 1: modify glibc

Now let's modify glibc with:

```
diff --git a/nptl/thrd_create.c b/nptl/thrd_create.c
index 113ba0d93e..b00f088abb 100644
--- a/nptl/thrd_create.c
+++ b/nptl/thrd_create.c
@@ -16,11 +16,14 @@
    License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
    <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

+#include <stdio.h>
+
 #include "thrd_priv.h"

 int
 thrd_create (thrd_t *thr, thrd_start_t func, void *arg)
 {
+  puts("hacked");
   _Static_assert (sizeof (thr) == sizeof (pthread_t),
                   "sizeof (thr) != sizeof (pthread_t)");
```

Then recompile and re-install glibc, and recompile and re-run our program:

```
cd glibc/build
make -j `nproc`
make -j `nproc` install
./test_glibc.sh
```

and we see `hacked` printed a few times as expected.

This further confirms that we actually used the glibc that we compiled and not the host one.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

### Setup 2: crosstool-NG pristine setup

This is an alternative to setup 1, and it is the most correct setup I've achieved far: everything is correct as far as I can observe, including the C runtime objects such as `crt1.o`, `crti.o`, and `crtn.o`.

In this setup, we will compile a full dedicated GCC toolchain that uses the glibc that we want.

The only downside to this method is that the build will take longer. But I wouldn't risk a production setup with anything less.

[crosstool-NG](https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng) is a set of scripts that downloads and compiles everything from source for us, including GCC, glibc and binutils.

Yes the GCC build system is so bad that we need a separate project for that.

This setup is only not perfect because [crosstool-NG does not support building the executables without extra `-Wl` flags](https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/issues/1030), which feels weird since we've built GCC itself. But everything seems to work, so this is only an inconvenience.

Get crosstool-NG, configure and build it:

```
git clone https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng
cd crosstool-ng
git checkout a6580b8e8b55345a5a342b5bd96e42c83e640ac5
export CT_PREFIX="$(pwd)/.build/install"
export PATH="/usr/lib/ccache:${PATH}"
./bootstrap
./configure --enable-local
make -j `nproc`
./ct-ng x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
./ct-ng menuconfig
env -u LD_LIBRARY_PATH time ./ct-ng build CT_JOBS=`nproc`
```

The build takes about thirty minutes to two hours.

The only mandatory configuration option that I can see, is making it match your host kernel version to use the correct kernel headers. Find your host kernel version with:

```
uname -a
```

which shows me:

```
4.15.0-34-generic
```

so in `menuconfig` I do:

- `Operating System`

  - `Version of linux`

so I select:

```
4.14.71
```

which is the first equal or older version. It has to be older since the kernel is backwards compatible.

#### Setup 2: optional configurations

The `.config` that we generated with `./ct-ng x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` has:

```
CT_GLIBC_V_2_27=y
```

To change that, in `menuconfig` do:

- `C-library`
- `Version of glibc`

save the `.config`, and continue with the build.

Or, if you want to use your own glibc source, e.g. to use glibc from the latest git, proceed [like this](https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/issues/1024):

- `Paths and misc options`

  - `Try features marked as EXPERIMENTAL`: set to true
- `C-library`

  - `Source of glibc`

    - `Custom location`: say yes
    - `Custom location`

      - `Custom source location`: point to a directory containing your glibc source

where glibc was cloned as:

```
git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git
cd glibc
git checkout glibc-2.28
```

#### Setup 2: test it out

Once you have built he toolchain that you want, test it out with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eux
install_dir="${CT_PREFIX}/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
PATH="${PATH}:${install_dir}/bin" \
  x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc \
  -Wl,--dynamic-linker="${install_dir}/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" \
  -Wl,--rpath="${install_dir}/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib" \
  -v \
  -o test_glibc.out \
  test_glibc.c \
  -pthread \
;
ldd test_glibc.out
./test_glibc.out
```

Everything seems to work as in Setup 1, except that now the correct runtime objects were used:

```
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS=/home/ciro/crosstool-ng/.build/install/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/../lib64/crt1.o
```

#### Setup 2: failed efficient glibc recompilation attempt

It does not seem possible with crosstool-NG, as explained below.

If you just re-build;

```
env -u LD_LIBRARY_PATH time ./ct-ng build CT_JOBS=`nproc`
```

then your changes to the custom glibc source location are taken into account, but it builds everything from scratch, making it unusable for iterative development.

If we do:

```
./ct-ng list-steps
```

it gives a nice overview of the build steps:

```
Available build steps, in order:
  - companion_tools_for_build
  - companion_libs_for_build
  - binutils_for_build
  - companion_tools_for_host
  - companion_libs_for_host
  - binutils_for_host
  - cc_core_pass_1
  - kernel_headers
  - libc_start_files
  - cc_core_pass_2
  - libc
  - cc_for_build
  - cc_for_host
  - libc_post_cc
  - companion_libs_for_target
  - binutils_for_target
  - debug
  - test_suite
  - finish
Use "<step>" as action to execute only that step.
Use "+<step>" as action to execute up to that step.
Use "<step>+" as action to execute from that step onward.
```

therefore, we see that there are glibc steps intertwined with several GCC steps, most notably `libc_start_files` comes before `cc_core_pass_2`, which is likely the most expensive step together with `cc_core_pass_1`.

In order to build just one step, you must first set the "Save intermediate steps" in `.config` option for the intial build:

- `Paths and misc options`

  - `Debug crosstool-NG`

    - `Save intermediate steps`

and then you can try:

```
env -u LD_LIBRARY_PATH time ./ct-ng libc+ -j`nproc`
```

but unfortunately, the `+` required as mentioned at: https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/issues/1033#issuecomment-424877536

> Note however that restarting at an intermediate step resets the installation directory to the state it had during that step. I.e., you will have a rebuilt libc - but no final compiler built with this libc (and hence, no compiler libraries like libstdc++ either).

and basically still makes the rebuild too slow to be feasible for development, and I don't see how to overcome this without patching crosstool-NG.

Furthermore, starting from the `libc` step didn't seem to copy over the source again from `Custom source location`, further making this method unusable.

### Bonus: stdlibc++

A bonus if you're also interested in the C++ standard library: [How to edit and re-build the GCC libstdc++ C++ standard library source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872229/how-to-edit-and-re-build-the-gcc-libstdc-c-standard-library-source/51946224#51946224)

Comment: I am going to use the crosstool-ng idea. But I'm going to use the latest [crosstool-ng](https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/releases/tag/crosstool-ng-1.25.0) release rather than the commit referenced above.

Answer (score 13):

@msb gives a safe solution.

I met this problem when I did `import tensorflow as tf` in conda environment in `CentOS 6.5` which only has `glibc-2.12`.

```
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by /home/
```

I want to supply some details:

First install `glibc` to your home directory:

```
mkdir ~/glibc-install; cd ~/glibc-install
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.17.tar.gz
tar -zxvf glibc-2.17.tar.gz
cd glibc-2.17
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=/home/myself/opt/glibc-2.17  # <-- where you install new glibc
make -j<number of CPU Cores>  # You can find your <number of CPU Cores> by using **nproc** command
make install
```

Second, follow the same way to install [patchelf](https://nixos.org/patchelf.html);

Third, patch your Python:

```
[myself@nfkd ~]$ patchelf --set-interpreter /home/myself/opt/glibc-2.17/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --set-rpath /home/myself/opt/glibc-2.17/lib/ /home/myself/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/bin/python
```

as mentioned by @msb

Now I can use `tensorflow-2.0 alpha` in `CentOS 6.5`.

ref: https://serverkurma.com/linux/how-to-update-glibc-newer-version-on-centos-6-x/

Comment: Hello, this works but... after setting the python (actually I set the python residing in the virtual environment) then it gives the following error: ***python3.8: error while loading shared libraries: libexpat.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory***

Comment: Check your path order, and double check the path to the libexpat.so.1. The error message says it cannot find.

Answer (score 7):

Can you consider using Nix http://nixos.org/nix/ ?

> Nix supports multi-user package management: multiple users can share a
>   common Nix store securely, don’t need to have root privileges to
>   install software, and can install and use different versions of a
>   package.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that the question is still relevant, but there is another way of fixing the problem: Docker. One can install an almost empty container of the Source Distribution (The Distribution used for development) and copy the files into the Container. That way You do not need to create the filesystem needed for chroot.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the second output you can see that the new location for the libraries is used. Maybe there are still missing libraries that are part of the glibc.

I also think that all the libraries used by your program should be compiled against that version of glibc. If you have access to the source code of the program, a fresh compilation appears to be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

"Employed Russian" is among the best answer, and I think all other suggested answer may not work.   The reason is simply because when an application is first created, all its the APIs it needs are resolved at compile time.   Using "ldd" u can see all the statically linked dependencies:

```
ldd /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd5c5f0000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f727e708000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f727e500000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f727e1f8000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f727def0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f727db28000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f727eb78000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f727d910000)
```

But at runtime, firefox will also load many other dynamic libraries, eg (for firefox) there are many "glib"-labelled libraries loaded (even though statically linked there are none):

```
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-glib-1.so.2.2.2
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4002.0
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-glib.so.1.0.2
```

Manytimes, you can see names of one version being soft-linked into another version.  Eg:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 Dec 21  2014 libdbus-glib-1.so.2 -> libdbus-glib-1.so.2.2.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 160832 Mar  1  2013 libdbus-glib-1.so.2.2.2
```

This therefore means different version of "libraries" exists in one system - which is not a problem as it is the same file, and it will provide compatibilities when applications have multiple versions dependencies.

Therefore, at the system level, all the libraries are almost interdependent on one another, and just changing the libraries loading priority via manipulating LD_PRELOAD or LD_LIBRARY_PATH will not help - even it can load, runtime it may still crash.

http://lightofdawn.org/wiki/wiki.cgi/-wiki/NewAppsOnOldGlibc

Best alternative is chroot (mentioned by ER briefly):   but for this you will need to recreate the entire environment in which is the original binary execute - usually starting from /lib, /usr/lib/, /usr/lib/x86 etc.   You can either use "Buildroot", or YoctoProject, or just tar from an existing Distro environment.   (like Fedora/Suse etc).

Answer (score 1):

When I wanted to run a chromium-browser on Ubuntu precise (glibc-2.15), I got the
(typical) message "...libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.19' not found...".
I considered the fact, that files are not needed permamently, but only for start.
So I collected the files needed for the browser and sudo and created a mini-glibc-2.19-
environment, started the browser and then copied the original files back 
again. The needed files are in RAM and the original glibc is the same.

```
as root
the files (*-2.15.so) already exist
```

mkdir -p /glibc-2.19/i386-linux-gnu

```
/glibc-2.19/ld-linux.so.2 -> /glibc-2.19/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
/glibc-2.19/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.19.so
/glibc-2.19/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.19.so
/glibc-2.19/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.19.so
```

mkdir -p /glibc-2.15/i386-linux-gnu

```
/glibc-2.15/ld-linux.so.2 -> (/glibc-2.15/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so)
/glibc-2.15/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 -> (libc-2.15.so)
/glibc-2.15/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 -> (libdl-2.15.so)
/glibc-2.15/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 -> (libpthread-2.15.so)
```

the script to run the browser:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo cp -r /glibc-2.19/* /lib
/path/to/the/browser &
sleep 1
sudo cp -r /glibc-2.15/* /lib
sudo rm -r /lib/i386-linux-gnu/*-2.19.so
```

Comment: Someone who has access to the correct libc at a different path than /lib or /lib64 would benefit from [msb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44710599/712526), which covers how to change the path to libc for the executable.

Answer (score 0):

As I was reading with a lot of interest [Employed Russian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/) as well as [msb's answer](https://msb), I found another quite simple method (which perhaps wasn't available when the question was initially asked...)

First, it is sufficient to [build without installing](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds#Building_glibc_without_installing) a glibc version of your choice.
Then, to start your app with the glibc dynamic loader that you've just built (rather than the dynamic loaded that's installed on your system), use the approach mentioned [here](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds#Compile_normally.2C_run_under_new_glibc): simply do `/path/to/glibc-build/testrun.sh /path/to/test/application`