# UNIX Portable Atomic Operations

Tags: c, concurrency, posix, atomic

Is there a (POSIX-)portable way in C for atomic variable operations similar to a portable threading with pthread?

Atomic operations are operations like "increment and get" that are executed atomically that means that no context switch can interfere with the operation. In Linux kernel space, we have to [atomic_t](http://lxr.linux.no/linux/+code=atomic_t) type, in Java we have the [java.util.concurrent.atomic](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) package.

On Linux, the atomic.h file provides atomic operations, but the include is platform dependent e.g. `#include <asm-x86_64/atomic.h>` and it is not available on Mac OS X in a similar way.

Comment: There are some GCC built-ins, [described here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html).

Comment: Nice, limited to GCC, but it would be fine for me.

Comment: and here for newer gcc: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of C11 there is an optional [Atomic library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) which provides atomic operations. This is portable to whatever platform that has a C11 compiler (like gcc-4.9) with this optional feature.

The presence of the atomic can be checked with `__STDC_NO_ATOMICS__`and the presence of `<stdatomic.h>`

**atomic.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifndef __STDC_NO_ATOMICS__
#include <stdatomic.h>
#endif

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    _Atomic int a;
    atomic_init(&a, 42);
    atomic_store(&a, 5);
    int b = atomic_load(&a);
    printf("b = %i\n", b);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Compiler invocations**

```
clang -std=c11 atomic.c
gcc -std=c11 atomic.c
```

Answer (score 14):

For anyone who stumbles upon this in the future, C11 atomics are the best way to do this now - I believe they will be included in GCC 4.9.

Comment: Can you expand on this?

Comment: Minimal runnable C11 atomics + threads example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130018/unix-portable-atomic-operations/54680209#54680209

Answer (score 11):

Since you asked for OS X:

(and since cross platformity was raised in this thread.)

OS X has functions **OSAtomicAdd32()** and friends. They are declared in "/usr/include/libkern/OSAtomic.h".
See [The Threading Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1), section "Using Atomic Operations".

And for Windows, there is **InterlockedIncrement()** and friends (see MSDN).

Together with the gcc builtins **__sync_fetch_and_add()** and friends (has been linked above), you should have
something for every main desktop platform.

Please note that I did not yet use them by myself, but maybe will do so in the next few days.

Answer (score 5):

No, POSIX does not specify *any* portable lock-free/atomic operations. That's why they have pthreads.

You're either going to have to use non-standard ways or stick with ptrheads for portability.

Answer (score 4):

**C11 atomics minimal runnable example**

With the addition of threads in glibc 2.28, we can do both atomics and threading in pure C11.

Example from: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <threads.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

atomic_int acnt;
int cnt;

int f(void* thr_data)
{
    for(int n = 0; n < 1000; ++n) {
        ++cnt;
        ++acnt;
        // for this example, relaxed memory order is sufficient, e.g.
        // atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&acnt, 1, memory_order_relaxed);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    thrd_t thr[10];
    for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
        thrd_create(&thr[n], f, NULL);
    for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
        thrd_join(thr[n], NULL);

    printf("The atomic counter is %u\n", acnt);
    printf("The non-atomic counter is %u\n", cnt);
}
```

Compile and run:

```
gcc -std=c11 main.c -pthread
./a.out
```

Possible output:

```
The atomic counter is 10000
The non-atomic counter is 8644
```

The non-atomic counter is very likely to be smaller than the atomic one due to racy access across threads to the non atomic variable.

A pthreads example can be found at: [How do I start threads in plain C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810/how-do-i-start-threads-in-plain-c/52453291#52453291)

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04 (glibc 2.27) by compiling glibc from source: [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host/52454603#52454603) Ubuntu 18.10 has glibc 2.28 so things should just work there.

Comment: But in case we stuck with glibc 2.27 would stdatomic work with `pthreads`?

Comment: glibc 2.28 comes with Ubuntu 18.10 or 19.04

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are no cross-platform ways to do atomic operations.  There may be a library out there but I don't know of.  Its not particularly hard to roll your own, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is.

One way of solving it, licenses permitting of course, would be to copy the relevant per-architecture implementations from e.g. the Linux kernel space. I haven't followed the evolution of those primitives closely, but I would guess that they are indeed primitives, i.e. don't depend upon other services or APIs in the kernel.