# Trying to cause a read or write error in multi-threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

How come the following doesn't give me a read / write error ever?
In my main thread I increment i, which is a read, and a write.
In both threads I write to total.
I would expect to see an error, but I leave it running and never get one, why is this?

For reference, my computer has 2 cores, 4 logical cores, its an Intel i3.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace Threading001
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int total = 0;

            new Thread(() => {
                var service2 = new Service();
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        total += i;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error from thread 2: {0}", ex);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }).Start();

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    total += i;
                    i++;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error from thread 1: {0}", ex);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What error you expecting and why there should be an error?

Comment: You will need to write code with a predicable (single-threaded) value for  'total' and then you may see deviation with threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both threads may update `total` at the same time, the error you may get is a "corrupted" total. i.e.: that `total` doesn't contain the "correct" sum. However, it won't throw an Exception.

If you want to do this kind of things and avoid any potential error, you could use [Interlocked.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33821kfh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Interlocked.Add(ref total, i)
```

Here is a simplified example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace Threading001
{
  class Program
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int total = 0;

        Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
            for ( int j=0 ; j < 1000000 ; j++)
            {
                Interlocked.Add(ref total, 1);
                //total++; //not thread-safe
            }
        });
        thread.Start();

        for ( int i=0 ; i < 1000000 ; i++)
        {
            Interlocked.Add(ref total, 1);
            //total++; //not thread-safe
        }

        thread.Join();

        Console.WriteLine(total);
    }
  }
}
```

With the version not thread safe, I get a different total each time (eg: 1425407, 1109498, ...).

With the thread safe version, I get 2000000 every time.

So, conclusion: if both threads try to write at the same time, I won't get the results I want. However, it won't throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

`race condition` does not throw an exception.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

notice the **Example**

here is the question in a "correct" manner

[pthreads: If I increment a global from two different threads, can there be sync issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673208/pthreads-if-i-increment-a-global-from-two-different-threads-can-there-be-sync)

Comment: he has 2 threads increasing same variable. and he asks why he does not get an exception.

Comment: Thanks Nahum, your answer was really good, and cleared up miss-assumptions I had about this example. The example on the Wiki page was spot on! But I also liked gturri's answer, and alas I can only pick one answer.

Comment: Sure. you should take time and take Modern Operating Systems Course.

https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fit.tdt.edu.vn%2F~tttin%2Fgiangday%2FHDH%2FModern%2520Operating%2520Systems.pdf

is the book they use in the university I attend.