# How to create atomic section in c

Tags: c, atomic

I need to perform part of some code atomically. 
I tried to search for information and I didn't get a specific answer.

lets say the code is:

```
//ATOMIC
unlock A
lock B
//ATOMIC END
```

- Is it possible to make this operation atomic in c ?
- Does it depends on my processor?
- Is there any simple function who does that?
- (These instructions are on the user side)

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130018/unix-portable-atomic-operations

Comment: @Geesh_SO , I'm not sure how to use this. I want to make `unlock A + lock B` atomic. I don't want to do `add` or `sub` ...

Comment: I don't believe there are, atomic lock/unlock sounds a bit strange. Maybe if you described your actual use case someone could help you.