# <stdatomic.h> in GCC 4.8?

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, atomic, c11

I'd like to make use of the new atomic operations provided by the C11 standard. However, trying to `#include` the appropriate header file gives me this:

```
 csort-par.c:5:23: fatal error: stdatomic.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdatomic.h>
```

The documentation at http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status seems to say that the header file has been provided since GCC 4.7... am I missing something? `__STDC_NO_ATOMICS__` is not defined.

`gcc --version` is as follows:

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

And I confirmed that `__STDC_NO_ATOMICS__` was not defined as follows:

```
#ifdef __STDC_NO_ATOMICS__
#error yes
#else
#error no
#endif
```

yields:

```
csort-par.c:10:2: error: #error no
 #error no
```

EDIT: Thanks for the swift replies.

In case anyone stumbles on this from Google with the same question, here's a fix in the interim until they release GCC 4.9:

[UNIX Portable Atomic Operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130018/unix-portable-atomic-operations)

Comment: It was a typo in copying, I'll fix it

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This file is missing. http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58016

It was fixed only in gcc 4.9, as its release notes says (http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html)

Comment: Yes exactly, I checked that :)

Comment: @Jekyll thanks, don't have 4.9 at work so was unable to verify, but've red it in release notes about a week ago. Although i doubt mere copying file from 4.9 to previous versions will work - as it makes heavy use of `_Atomic`, which looks unavailable on previous versions.

Comment: I don't have 4.9 as well but I could verify (see answer below) that previous versions only give support for c++ std::atomic extension. I searched on my path and I verified that being true. Moreover seems to be documented,infact the bug there was rejected basically telling that an "incomplete documented feature" cannot be reported as a bug.