# gcc: Reduce libc required version

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, libc

I am trying to run a newly compiled binary on some oldish 32bits RedHat distribution.
The binary is compiled C (not++) on a CentOS 32bits VM running libc v2.12.

RedHat complains about libc version:

```
error while loading shared libraries: requires glibc 2.5 or later dynamic linker
```

Since my program is rather simplistic, It is most likely not using anything new from libc.

**Is there a way to reduce libc version requirement**

Comment: This answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856438/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-glibc-version

Answer (score 25, accepted):

An untested possible solution

> **What is "error while loading shared libraries: requires glibc 2.5 or later dynamic linker"?**
>
> The cause of this error is the dynamic binary (or one of its dependent
>   shared libraries) you want to run only has .gnu.hash section, but the
>   ld.so on the target machine is too old to recognize .gnu.hash; it only
>   recognizes the old-school .hash section.
>
> This usually happens when the dynamic binary in question is built
>   using newer version of GCC. The solution is to recompile the code with
>   either -static compiler command-line option (to create a static
>   binary), or the following option:
>
> ```
> -Wl,--hash-style=both
> ```
>
> This tells the link editor ld to create both .gnu.hash and .hash
>   sections.
>
> According to [ld documentation here](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html), the old-school .hash section
>   is the default, but the compiler can override it. For example, the GCC
>   (which is version 4.1.2) on RHEL (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) Server
>   release 5.5 has this line:
>
> ```
> $ gcc -dumpspecs
> ....
> *link:
> %{!static:--eh-frame-hdr} %{!m32:-m elf_x86_64} %{m32:-m elf_i386} --hash-style=gnu   %{shared:-shared}   ....
>                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ...
> ```
>
> For more information, [see here](http://crtags.blogspot.com/2010/11/elf-elf-elf-dont-do-it.html).

Comment: Unfortunately the -Wl flags is not digested by my gcc -m32

Comment: @AknownImous: what is the error you get?  The 'argument to the `-Wl,` option is just passed to the linker - are you linking using `gcc` or are you invoking `ld` or some other linker directly?  Also, note that there cannot be a space in the `-Wl,--hash-style=both` option.

Comment: gcc is complaining about "unrecognized command line option -Wl". I am only using gcc.

Comment: @AknownImous: Can you copy/paste your gcc command line and the output of `gcc -v`?  The `-Wl` option is documented even for GCC 2.95.3 which was released in 2001 so I'm surprised your gcc has trouble with it.

Comment: In 2017 this has also worked for me.  My web hosting company web server, which seems to be Centos, happily runs a compiled C binary I built on Debian in 2006 but refused to run one rebuilt now on Fedora 17.  Following this answer, compared old and new using "readelf -a" on each.  Sure enough under "Section Headers:" and elsewhere, the new one has "  [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        08048".... whereas the old one has "  [ 3] .hash             HASH            08048128 "...So I added flags "-Wl,--hash-style=sysv" to gcc link line and all is good.

Comment: Confirming; I see this error when compiling with gcc 6.3.0 20170205 on `4.6.0-kali1-686 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) i686 GNU/Linux` for CentOS 4.8. Propose solution works for me.

Comment: I used this command `-Wl,--hash-style=both` and it resolved my issues.  Thank you.

Comment: Everyone pay attention, it is: `-Wl,--hash-style=both` (with no space between `-Wl,` and `--hash-style=both` )

Answer (score 5):

I already had the same problem, trying to compile a little tool (I wrote) for an old machine for which I had not compiler. I compiled it on an up to date machine, and the binary required at least GLIBC 2.14 in order to run.

By making a dump of the binary (with xxd), I found this :

```
....
5f64 736f 5f68 616e 646c 6500 6d65 6d63  _dso_handle.memc
7079 4040 474c 4942 435f 322e 3134 005f  py@@GLIBC_2.14._
....
```

So I replaced the memcpy calls in my code by a call to an home-made memcpy, and the dependency with the glibc 2.14 magically disappeared.

I'm sorry I can't really explain why it worked, or I can't explain why it didn't work before the modification.

Hope it helped !

Comment: Nice catch, but rewriting stdlib looks a bit scary !

Comment: Yes I'm agree, but in that case, the code is very small, and memcpy is called only 3 times in my code

Answer (score 3):

Ok then, trying to find some balance between elegance and brute force, I downloaded a **VM matching the target kernel** version, hence fixing library issues.
The whole thing (download + yum install gcc) took less than 30 minutes.

References: [Virtual machines](http://www.thoughtpolice.co.uk/vmware/), [Kernel Version Mapping Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS#Release_history)