# How do you call a function with the same symbol in 2 different shared libraries?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, qnx

I have several versions of the same library written in C++. I need to compare them side-by-side. These libraries use the same namespace, function names and take the same parameters.

Are there any methods to control which version of the library I use when I link two or more of them at the same time?

Comment: AFAIK, you'd get a linker error complaining about multiple defined symbols. No?

Comment: you can't link two libs with the same symbols, linker will simply refuse to do it.

Comment: Well. Glibc has symbol versioning (have a look [at this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856438/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-glibc-version) for example), an approach which might help you if you can rebuild your libraries to include such metadata.

Comment: Don't link against it; `dlopen()`, but be prepared for a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to say that I was working on the QNX platform, where I could link to 2 of such libraries. The program compiles and can actually run. It just calls one of the libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot link two libraries with identical symbols and get access to both. However, you can build your own thin wrapper libraries to disambiguate the two versioned libraries:

- Define an abstract class `Wrapper` that exercises the functions of the target library using abstract virtual functions
- Define an implementation of `Wrapper` in a class called `WrapperImpl` that calls through to the target library from the virtual methods
- Define a free-standing method `Wrapper *MakeImpl` returning `new WrapperImpl()`
- Compile `WrapperImpl` into static libraries several times, linking with different versions of the target library each time. **Critical:** pass `-DWrapperImpl=WrapperImplV1 -DMakeImpl=MakeImplV1` to the compiler, with `V1`, `V2`, `V3`, and so on, for different versions. You should end up with multiple libraries.
- Link your main tester with these multiple libraries

At this point, your main tester has access to free-standing functions `MakeImplV1`, `MakeImplV2`, `MakeImplV3` and so on created through renaming `MakeImpl` through the preprocessor. Use these functions to obtain instances of `Wrapper` that call through to different versions of the target library.

Comment: I'd be tempted to make the interface for this Wrapper library a single function `Wrapper* GetWrapper()`.  Well, actually, `Wrapper* GetWrapperV1()` etc.  Then the define replacement only has to happen on a single token in the library -- the name of the GetWrapper function.  A pure-virtual Wrapper interface doesn't have to have symbols exported in order to be used by the client under (some?)(most?)(all?) C++ linking architectures (the layout of the pure virtual class is sufficient), and the WrapperImpl is a private implementation detail that you don't export.

Comment: @Yakk That is pretty much what's going on here. The `WrapperImplV1` name is not used - all access is done through the `MakeImplV<N>` functions, the only entry point to his version-specific libraries.