# How to install old version of Glibc on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, glibc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I link to a specific glibc version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856438/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-glibc-version)

I have a `Ubuntu server` with `glibc 2.7`, how can i install to this machine `glibc` of older version, for example `2.2` or `2.0`.

Thanks!

Comment: Download & build it?  Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?