# Tell which version of symbols are available for linking against (in libc)?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, glibc, libc

Ok, so I want to link against a lower version of libc / glibc, for compatibility.  I noticed this answer about how to do this, on a case-by-case basis:

[How can I link to a specific glibc version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856438/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-glibc-version)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2858996/920545

However, when I tried to apply this myself, I ran into problems, because I can't figure out what lower-version-number I should use to link against.  Using the example in the answer, if I use "nm" to inspect the symbols provided by my /lib/libc.so.6 (which, in my case, is a link to libc-2.17.so), I see that it seems to provide versions 2.0 and 2.3 of realpath:

```
> nm /lib/libc.so.6 | grep realpath@
4878d610 T realpath@@GLIBC_2.3
48885c20 T realpath@GLIBC_2.0
```

However, if I try to link against realpath@GLIBC_2.0:

```
__asm__(".symver realpath,realpath@GLIBC_2.0");
```

...i get an error:

```
> gcc -o test_glibc test_glibc.c
/tmp/ccMfnLmS.o: In function `main':
test_glibc.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `realpath@GLIBC_2.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, using realpath@GLIBC_2.3 works... and the code from the example, realpath@GLIBC_2.2.5 works - even though, according to nm, no such symbol exists.  (FYI, if I compile without any `__asm__` instruction, then inspect with nm, I see that it linked against realpath@GLIBC_2.3, which makes sense; and I confirmed that linking to realpath@GLIBC_2.2.5 works.)

So, my question is, how the heck to I know which version of the various functions I can link against? Or even which are available? Are there some other kwargs I should be feeding to nm? Am I inspecting the wrong library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have mixed up your libraries and binaries a bit...

`/lib/libc.so.6` on most Linux distributions is a 32-bit shared object and should contain the `*@GLIBC_2.0` symbols. If you are on an x86_64 platform, though, I would expect GCC to produce an 64-bit binary by default. 64-bit binaries are generally linked against `/lib64/libc.so.6`, which would not contain compatibility symbols for an old glibc version like 2.0 - the x86_64 architecture did not even exist back then...

Try compiling your `*@GLIBC_2.0` program with the `-m32` GCC flag to force linking against the 32-bit C library.

Comment: *facepalm* Yup, you're right... I was indeed looking at the /lib/ instead of /lib64/ binary.  Thanks for pointing out the obvious!