# Glibc version mismatch

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have created .so library in my Ubuntu and run it on another machine. Got error:

```
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found
```

I suppose this is general C++ library. But how to solve such problem? I can't change client configuration and that means I must to do something with my configuration. But what exactly I must do?

UPD

`ldd -version` returns

my machine:

```
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) 2.19
```

host machine:

```
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.8) 2.11.1
```

Answer (score 2):

On the target machine, run **ldd --version** and check the output which will tell you what version of GLIBC_ they have.

1. You can then roll yours back to match their version.
2. Statically link your executable so it doesn't need their Clib.
3. You can also alter your program to use the older version, once you know what it is, that is.

See this SO solution for how to do that. [How can I link to a specific glibc version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856438/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-glibc-version)

Comment: I have updated my question body with ldd -version return. Strange that none of them have 2.15 version

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that you are linking to corresponding or older versions of GLIBC. GCC has flag `--sysroot` which allows you to define which libs are used.

This may help with details: https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds

Answer (score 0):

The point is that creating a shared library necessarily means that you need to link it to the C library (glibc, in your case). That means that calls to C library functions (which the stdc++ library does) get replaced with actual correct symbol locations in the C library.

Now, if the C library on the compiling/linking machine is not the same as on the target machine, this *must* fail, and hence, libc version gets checked.

Solutions is to either statically link your .so (which honestly doesn't make much sense, usually), or just correctly compile and link it for your target machine.

Comment: to link it to correct version of glibc I suppose I need to install it on my machine. But how how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Beside compiling everything static, which is usually a bad
idea or does not work at all, the only way to solve the isssue 
is to recompile your binary for the target platform.

Install a virtual machine or chroot with the same Ubuntu version 
as on the target platform and compile there. There are also solutions
like `sbuild` or `pbuilder/cowbuilder` which automates this for Debian/Ubuntu packages.