# CMake: Linking statically against libgcc and libstdc++ into a shared library

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, g++, static-linking

**Problem:**

I am having difficulties linking glibcc/glibc++ into a shared library using CMake and GCC4.9 on my Ubuntu 16.04 installation.

**Additional conditions:**

Loading the shared library gives a problem om the Red Hat production environment(where I copy it to), I believe because it uses a different libstc++ version(error: GLIBCXX_3_4_20 not found). I do not have sudo rights and cannot upgrade the machine.

As I derived from [this](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/06/static-libstdc/) blog, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856438/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-glibc-version), I tried linking static linking against libgcc and libgc++ using:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static")
```

and againg using

```
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static")
```

But that doesn't work. What *does* work is this CMake script:

```
add_library(myLib SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS " -static")
target_link_libraries(myLib -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++)
```

This must be the wrong way of doing this, to my knowledge -static-libgcc and  -static-libstdc++ are linker options and not libraries...

**Question**:
How do I link statically against -libgcc and -libstdc++ correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, `target_link_libraries` is a *correct way to set linker flags* or  linker options.

Documentation of `target_link_libraries`:

> Specify libraries or *flags* to use when linking a given target.
>
> Item names starting with -, but not -l or -framework, are treated as
> linker flags.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html (emphasis not in original)

Comment: Thanks! Ok, I should have read the manual better... I think the name target_link_libraries is a bit confusing though...

Comment: Guess it also means "target link flags" but yeah...

Answer (score 8):

As of cmake 3.13, there is a new cmake function for general linker options:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/target_link_options.html

```
target_link_options(<target> [BEFORE]
  <INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [items1...]
  [<INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [items2...] ...])
```

The appropriate way to specify libraries to be linked is still:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/target_link_libraries.html

```
target_link_libraries(<target>
  <PRIVATE|PUBLIC|INTERFACE> <item>...
  [<PRIVATE|PUBLIC|INTERFACE> <item>...]...)
```

There are a few different signatures depending on whether or not you want these libraries to be propagated to dependent targets, so be sure to check the docs.

Comment: Why couldn't you just show the exact code... would have been much easier..

Comment: `target_link_options(myLib PRIVATE -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++)`