# Let CMake link against specific version of libstdc++

Tags: gcc, cmake, stl, g++, static-linking

I'm working on a fresh installed Debian-12 at where only the version 11/12 of gcc/g++ can be installed against the official apt repository.

But my producing target app must be compiled with g++-9, so I have built gcc-9.5.0 from source and installed it.

I can use gcc-9/g++-9 to make my app, but I found that it still is linked against the STL that come with g++-12.

Although I can re-make a symbolic link that points to the new compiled libstdc++.so in order to let my app to really use the expected STL, but I'm afraid that would mess my working system(All other apps of the whole KDE desktop are using libstdc++).

So I decided to link *statically* my app against the STL of the version my own compiled.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38696028/10441038) has pointed out the way "how to statically link against STL", but it didn't talk about "how to link against a specific version of STL in CMake".

For example, my own compiled STL has been installed on `/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.a`, while my working system native STL is siting on `/lib64/libstdc++.a`, How to let the cmake to use the STL as my expecting?

Comment: libstdc++ is not STL.

Comment: @273K Oh! I always treat it as STL!!!

Comment: "I found that it still is linked against the STL that come with g++-12." I doubt you found this. What you likely found is that *on your build machine*, when the dynamic linker searches for libstdc++, it finds the one that is installed in the default place. This is by design, as it allows seamless upgrades of libraries. For example, you compile against libstdc++-9, then you upgrade your machine, you now have libstdc++-12, but your program keeps working.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI right! But the producing system is Debian-12 too, now my app doesn't run as before(compile/link with g++-9).  Indeed I need to make it entirely with g++9 and STL-9!  How to let my app using a specific version of a *.so?   I can't control it when dynamic loading.

Comment: Further more, I think it is easy to maintain producing env, if we link statically the app. At least it uses lib's version as expecting.

Comment: "I need to make it entirely with g++9" It isn't clear why. What's the problem of using up-to-date tools and libraries? Anyway, if you compile your entire program including any third-party libraries, you can link against libstdc++ statically by using `-static-libstdc++` compiler flag.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI appretiate your patience!  I found some strange different behavior between the target codes compiled respectively by g++-9 and g++-11. The codes built with former works as expecting, but the codes built with latter doesn't.

Comment: Perhaps there is a bug in your program, you should try and find it.