# Specifying the kernel version (shown by 'file') an executable is for?

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, arm, cross-compiling

I was trying to cross compile a simple hello world program for ARM using an x86-64 PC. The board has linux kernel version 2.6.35, so `kernel too old` error occurs for programs that are `for GNU/Linux 3.x.x`.

When using `gcc`, `file a.out` shows info `for GNU/Linux 2.6.32`.
While using `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`, `file a.out` shows info `for GNU/Linux 3.2.0`.

Is there a way of specifying what kernel version a gcc-compiled program is for? If so, how could I achieve that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Refer this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52677/compile-software-with-older-version-of-gcc-and-linux-kernel) on Unix and Linux StackExchange.

Comment: Thanks for your information. In my case, both `gcc` and `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` show the same version number: `(Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609`, but the output programs target different kernel version.

Comment: You have to use an older version of `glibc` for Linux kernel 2.6.35. Download an older glibc perhaps version 2.3.4 version of glibc should work.

Comment: I have come cross this hint, but don't know how to work it out. Do you have any resource or tutorial for changing the glibc version gcc uses? Sorry I am quite new to Linux; thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe this should help you [How can I link to a specific glibc version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856438/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-glibc-version).

Comment: That seems promising, I'll try it out. thank you.

Comment: There's another simple solution => static compile. If the size of your program is not that huge, static compile allows you to ignore a synchronization issue in ABI (library level). :)