# How to install extra ARM64 library package onto a x64 Ubuntu box?

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, arm64

I have a `t_cap_get_file.c` file(from the book [TLPI](https://man7.org/tlpi/)) who uses function `cap_get_file`, `cap_to_text` etc.

Using Ubuntu Linux 20.04, in order to compile successfully with native gcc, I need to `sudo apt install libcap-dev`. Now I have `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.a` and compile and link both OK.

Next, I want to compile it for ARM64, so I install ARM64 gcc compiler with command：

```
sudo apt install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
```

Now I have `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc`. Then go on.

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -g  t_cap_get_file.c -lcap
```

And it fails. The linker(ld) says **cannot find -lcap** .

Then my question is, how can I get ARM64-version `libcap.a`？ the following `apt install` brings no luck.

```
$ sudo apt install libcap-dev:aarch64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libcap-dev:aarch64
```

[image: ARM64 link fail, due to lack of -lcap]

Sample code below:

```
#include <sys/capability.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define errExit(msg)    do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
                        } while (0)

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cap_t caps;
    char *str;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <pathname>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Fetch and display file capabilities */

    caps = cap_get_file(argv[1]);

    if (caps == NULL) {
        if (errno == ENODATA)
            printf("No capabilities are attached to this file\n");
        else
            errExit("cap_get_file");
    } else {
        str = cap_to_text(caps, NULL);
        if (str == NULL)
            errExit("cap_to_text");

        printf("Capabilities: %s\n", str);

        cap_free(str);
    }

    cap_free(caps);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: "Installing things just to link against them" is one of those things that Linux completely and utterly fails at. I think this falls into the same bucket as [installing a specific version of a library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2856438/2302862). The solution I came up with was to manually compile a list of URLs to all the packages I need in order to link, and then have a simple bash script fetch and extract them into a folder, and use that as `--sysroot`.