# Does the C language have support for multi-threading?

Tags: c, multithreading, compiler-construction

Since C Language does not provide any object oriented concepts, I wonder whether it also does not have support for multi-threading? I searched on the web - can anyone give me answer regarding this?

Comment: Multi-threading is certainly not dependant of object oriented concepts. Take a look at the pthread library: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/.

Comment: I'm not trying to be a jerk, but no, you didn't search for it: [Google "multithreading in c"](http://www.google.com/search?q=multithreading%20in%20c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start threads in plain C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810/how-do-i-start-threads-in-plain-c)

Answer (score 11):

With C11, the language has full support for threading, including the memory model it inherited from C++11. It has facilities for [threads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_create), [condition variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/cnd_init), [mutexes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/mtx_init) and [thread local storage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/tss_create), for instance.

Prior to C11, people typically used [pthreads](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread.h.html) on unix systems and [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on windows, which was supported via implementation defined behavior (not the C standard). Multithreading behavior would mostly defer to the behavior of that hardware.

Answer (score 2):

C is un-doubtfully have multi-threading support. Check out pthread. And here is an tutorial on pthread:

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: No, you are wrong. There are extensions that add this at top of C, but no current standard (c99) do support threading.
Posix Threads are not part of C standard.

Answer (score 1):

Whether a language is Object Oriented or not doesn't affect it's support for threading.

Yes you can use threads with C and there are various libraries you can use to do this, pthreads being one of them.

Answer (score 1):

**C1X** will support threading, but right now, there is **no such** thing in **c99**.
Peeople do use *less* portable extensions like POSIX threads (**pthreads**), **forking** etc.

**Standard C1X** is still a **draft** and support from compilers is somewhat lacking, gcc partially support it, but I heard threading isnt complete yet (I mean, unstable, dev version of gcc, not 4.6).

Answer (score 1):

Check these out:

- Read [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)
- See [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/about-openmp/)
- Have a look at [Cilk](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/cilk/)

And there is no relation between multithreaded computation and object oriented features. It will depend how you design your code, which will tell if it is object oriented or not.