# Multithreading in C

Tags: c, multithreading

I am new to multithreading, and any answers will be greatly appreciated. I am running an example from a tutorial which uses 3 threads; two created by the user, and one for main itself. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_EMPLOYEES 2

/* global mutex for our program. assignment initializes it */
pthread_mutex_t a_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

struct employee {
    int number;
    int id;
    char first_name[20];
    char last_name[30];
    char department[30];
    int room_number;
};

/* global variable - our employees array, with 2 employees */
struct employee employees[] = {
        {1, 12345678, "danny", "cohen", "Accounting", 101},
        {2, 87654321, "moshe", "levy", "Programmers", 202}
};

/* global variable - employee of the day */
struct employee employee_of_the_day;

void copy_employee(struct employee *from, struct employee *to) {
    int rc;     /* contain mutex lock/unlock results */

    /*lock the mutex, to assure exclusive access to 'a' and 'b' */
    rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&a_mutex);

    to->number = from->number;
    to->id = from->id;
    strcpy(to->first_name, from->first_name);
    strcpy(to->last_name, from->last_name);
    strcpy(to->department, from->department);
    to->room_number = from->room_number;

    /* unlock mutex */
    rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&a_mutex);
}

/* function to be executed by the variable setting threads thread */
void *do_loop(void *data) {
    int my_num = *((int*)data);

    while(1) {
        /* set employee of the day to be the one with number 'my_num' */
        copy_employee(&employees[my_num-1], &employee_of_the_day);
    }
}

/* program's execution begins in main */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    int thr_id1;
    int thr_id2;
    pthread_t p_thread1;
    pthread_t p_thread2;
    int num1 = 1;
    int num2 = 2;
    struct employee eotd;
    struct employee *worker;

    /* initialize employee of the day to first 1 */
    copy_employee(&employees[0], &employee_of_the_day);

    /* create a new thread that will execute 'do_loop()' with '1' */
    thr_id1 = pthread_create(&p_thread1, NULL, do_loop, (void*)&num1);

    /* create a new thread that will execute 'do_loop()' with '2' */
    thr_id2 = pthread_create(&p_thread2, NULL, do_loop, (void*)&num2);

    /* run a loop that verifies integrity of 'employee of the day' many */
    /* many times.... */
    for (i = 0; i < 600000; i++) {
        /* save contents of 'employee of the day' to local 'worker' */
        copy_employee(&employee_of_the_day, &eotd);
        worker = &employees[eotd.number-1];

        /* compare employees */
        if (eotd.id != worker->id) {
            printf("mismatching 'id', %d != %d (loop '%d')\n",
                    eotd.id, worker->id, i);
            exit(0);
        }
        if (strcmp(eotd.first_name, worker->first_name) != 0) {
            printf("mismatching 'first_name' , %s != %s (loop '%d')\n",
                    eotd.first_name, worker->first_name, i);
            exit(0);
        }
        if (strcmp(eotd.last_name, worker->last_name) != 0) {
            printf("mismatching 'last_name' , %s != %s (loop '%d')\n",
                    eotd.last_name, worker->last_name, i);
            exit(0);
        }
        if (strcmp(eotd.department, worker->department) != 0) {
            printf("mismatching 'department' , %s != %s (loop '%d')\n",
                    eotd.department, worker->department, i);
            exit(0);
        }
        if (eotd.room_number != worker->room_number) {
            printf("mismatching 'room_number' , %d != %d (loop '%d')\n",
                    eotd.room_number, worker->room_number, i);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    printf("Glory, employees contents was always consistent\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I basically want to confirm that in the for loop in main, the following statement

```
copy_employee(&employee_of_the_day, &eotd);
```

could be executed by ANY of the 3 threads; am I right? 
The fact that the subsequent comparisons are obviously not atomic raises some confusions. Any clarifications/corrections to this will be greatly helpful.

Incidentally, any good recommendations for tutorials on multithreading in C?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Minimal runnable example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810/how-do-i-start-threads-in-plain-c/52453291#52453291

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main thread (and none of the worker threads) will execute everything within `main()` and then end. Both of your worker threads will execute everything within `do_loop()` and end once they leave the function.

This sounds a bit like you're confusing `phtread_create()` with `fork()`. `pthread_create()` will use the function provided as the entry point while `fork()` will start from the position it's been called.

Comment: Great. So that means that when the call to copy_employee() is made in the for loop in main, any of the two worker threads could execute that function? Thanks!

Comment: All three threads call `copy_employee()` at some time, but with different parameters and from different positions in the code. The mutex lock ensures only one thread runs that copy code at the same time.

Comment: So just to be sure, everytime in the for loop, its the main's thread which runs copy_employee(), right? The fact that the code's author iterates for this many times was causing confusion.

Comment: Yes, only the main thread will run the loop inside `main()`. The worker threads only run code within `do_loop()`. To me it looks like it's looping that often to give the workers enough time to so something. I wouldn't call it good design, but it's just for learning purposes anyway. If this would be some kind of real database and `main` would be meant to verify the data, it would just be an infinite loop (or till the program has to end).

Answer (score 3):

No, the code in main is executed by only one thread.

The atomicity is ensured in copy_employee functions using mutexes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any ideas why the code's author ran the for loop so many times? Just to be sure, user created threads 1 and 2 run once, right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, they run only once. There is no obvious reason in the current implementation to run that loop many times. Maybe initially copy_employee was written without the mutex and he wanted to 'test' it ? Just a theory...

Answer (score 2):

> I basically want to confirm that in the for loop in main, the following statement
>
> copy_employee(&employee_of_the_day, &eotd);
>
> could be executed by ANY of the 3 threads; am I right?

Not really, since that statement is only executed by the main thread and not by the other two threads.