# Compiling glibc from source with debug symbols

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, linker, glibc

I need to compile glibc from source with debug symbols.

1. Where do I specify the `-g` option for this?
2. How do I later make a sample code link to this particular glibc rather than the one installed on my system?

Comment: If you are not familiar with compilation of *Glibc* I would avoid doing that. If you only need the debug information of *glibc*, install the appropriate packages providing it, e.g. `libc6-dbg` on Debian or Ubuntu...

Comment: That wouldnt help because i need to modify some of the files and check how they are working.

Comment: The hard part is how to actually use it afterwards: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810/how-do-i-start-threads-in-plain-c Good luck with that! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I need to compile glibc from source with debug symbols

You will have hard time compiling glibc *without* debug symbols. A default `./configure && make` *will* have `-g` on compile line.

> How do i later make a sample code link to this particular glibc rather than the one installed on my system?

This is somewhat tricky, and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).

Comment: `-g` apparently comes from: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=Makeconfig;h=751e9ffa32149ba8854cc6fb7404a5902305dc37;hb=HEAD#l341 in 2.21

Comment: No. At least not for compilation of files comprising the dynamic linker-loader (`ld.so[.new]`). Here's the captured invocation I got for one of them: `gcc dl-reloc.c -c -std=gnu11 -fgnu89-inline -O2 -Wall -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -fmerge-all-constants -frounding-math -fstack-protector-strong -march=x86-64 -pipe -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -fno-stack-protector -DSTACK_PROTECTOR_LEVEL=0 -ftls-model=initial-exec -I…`. There are _symbols_ in the resulting executable, but not full-fledged debug info one gets with `-g` (as can easily be seen with `dwarfdump` or by the mere size of it).

Answer (score 3):

It is probably a matter of `configure` tricks. First, try `configure --help` and then, either `configure --enable-debug` or perhaps `configure CC='gcc -g'` or even `configure CFLAGS='-g'`

For your sample code, perhaps consider playing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `LD_PRELOAD` tricks (assuming linking to dynamic library).

But be very careful, since the *Glibc* is the cornerstone of Gnu/Linux like systems.