# Can I use a case inside another case in a Switch Case in C

Tags: c, switch-statement, gtk, keyevent

Here, In the Switch Case I am using some key events.

When I press **0** it directs to **Case 0:** and goes back to the MainWindow I have, by closing the second-one(Window2).
And If I press **1** it directs to **Case 1** and so on respectively, where the operations will be  executed separatedly.

My key events:

```
    g_printerr("%s\n", gdk_keyval_name (event->keyval));
    keypressed=gdk_keyval_name (event->keyval);
    printf("The KeyEvent is: %s\n", keypressed);     
    char ch[10];
    sprintf(ch, "%s\n", keypressed);   
    printf("The NewKeyEvent is: %s\n", ch);
    int holdch=atoi(ch);
```

Switch Case:

```
switch(holdch)
         {
              case 0:
                   printf("Close Window2")
              break;   
              case 1:
                   printf("Open Quadrant1");
              break;
              case 2:
                   printf("Open Quadrant2");
              break;
              case 3:
                   printf("Open Quadrant3");
              break;
              case 4:
                   printf("Open Quadrant4");
              break;
           }
```

Now, I want to close the operations getting run from **Case(1-4)** when running and come back to the Second window from where it left before.

How to do this? Can another Cases be used inside **Case(1-4)**? This time I want to use key-buttons like *Esc* or *q* for that. Is it possible?

**NOTE:**

*Case 0*-> Close the window where I am now and after this there is no chance of executing other cases. As Second Window is the Window containing 4 Quadrants.

*Case(1-4)*-> All are executable but can be executed one at a time.

Comment: "I want to close the operations getting run from Case(1-4) when running"  What does this mean? Do you want to abort the code currently executed, or do you want to return after that code is done executing?

Comment: I want to abort the code currently executed. Its not I want to return after the ecexution.

Comment: @kkk tags? What is to use then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be another `switch` statement inside a cases (nested switch case statements). Example:

```
switch(keyevent) {
case 0:
    printf("Close Window2")
    break;   
case 1:
   printf("Open Quadrant1");
   switch(foo) {
   case 1:
       // ...
   }
   break;
   // ...
}
```

But, if I understand your use-case correctly, I don't think you need it.
How bout something like that:

```
switch(keyevent) {
case 0:
    printf("Close Window2")
    break;   
case 1:
    q1_is_open = true;
    printf("Open Quadrant1");
    break;
case 2:
    q2_is_open = true;
    printf("Open Quadrant2");
    break;
case 3:
    q3_is_open = true;
    printf("Open Quadrant3");
    break;
case 4:
    q4_is_open = true;
    printf("Open Quadrant4");
    break;
case Q_BUTTON_PRESSED:
    if (q1_is_open) {
        printf("Close Quadrant1");
        q1_is_open = false;
    }
    if (q2_is_open) {
        printf("Close Quadrant2");
        q2_is_open = false;
    }
    if (q3_is_open) {
        printf("Close Quadrant3");
        q3_is_open = false;
    }
    if (q4_is_open) {
        printf("Close Quadrant4");
        q4_is_open = false;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: Awesome :) But my confusion now is can I use Q as a event there? My key values are integer till now. I will edit and take a look I am showing my keyevents. How to take Q as a event so that it goes to **case Q_BUTTON_PRESSED:**

Comment: @djgharphalia07 Instead of Q_BUTTON_PRESSED you can use your integer value or `#define Q_BUTTON_PRESSED 42`

Comment: Sure :) I will try and let you know.

Comment: As far as I know, *If statements* inside *Cases* are not used so much as it takes time to execute. To overcome this Cases are used! Anyway it will be better if I could use another keys other than integers.

Comment: @djgharphalia07 Cases take also time to execute ;) A switch variable (key) has to be a value that can be expressed as an integer.

Comment: Ok :( but it is not taking value as 999 or 99...for veification I printed the key value as you have seen. It is taking only 9. Why?

Comment: @djgharphalia07 I cant say why without looking at the code.

Comment: **#define Q_BUTTON_PRESSED 99** I have just done this. As you suggested.

Comment: @djgharphalia07 Have you tested with `case 99:` instead of `case Q_BUTTON_PRESSED:` ?

Comment: Yes, I did :( Same. I cant close the selected quadrant.

Comment: If I take Case 9: or Case 5: or anything singular it works... How to send double values.

Comment: @djgharphalia07 Without looking at the code it would be just guessing. Maybe you should post another question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your main-window and quadrant-window code sequentially you'll need to run whatever you have in  cases 1-4 in a separate thread:

[How do I start threads in plain C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810/how-do-i-start-threads-in-plain-c)

The code in that thread will have to have a switch which processes the key strokes that you want to use for exiting it.

You can nest switch statements.

(If this doesn't help then you'll need to re-word your question.)

Comment: Your answer is informative too! And you get the reward :)