# Using a "beep function" parallel with other commands?

Tags: c, function, beep

Here's the issue: I'm making a Snake version on Code::Blocks (C programming) for a school project, and I got stuck at trying to exeute simultaneous actions in a single code. Long story short, I'd like to play a song ("many sequential Beeps") while the user chooses his option on a give menu. Problem is the program has to wait until the song is finished before it can scanf the given variable, just like in the code below.

```
int main()
{ 
    song();

    scanf(" %c",&option);

    printf("%c", option);

    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestion would be more than welcome. Thanks.

Comment: One obvious option is to use a seperate process or thread to play the song.

Comment: Threads are a very OS-specific thing, so we can't answer without knowing which OS you're using. Also, it might be nice to know what libraries you're using for things like `song()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend you use different **Threads** for both process you want to have simultaneously.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810/how-do-i-start-threads-in-plain-c) question regarding threads and forks.

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT:**

As noted by @Barmar take a closer look at the first link regarding [*threads*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810/how-do-i-start-threads-in-plain-c) (more useful for your question), where you will need to run one for each task you want simultaneously (that is beep and user input).

*Forks* would be useful if, for example, you need to duplicate your game process to have several instances of them. Given the question you asked, *threads* are the way to go.

Comment: Fork creates processes, not threads. The question you linked to says to use `pthread_create()` to create threads.

Comment: I linked to several questions. The other two give more reference specific to forks. The first one, as indicated, talks about threads.

Comment: But he doesn't need to use `fork()` at all. Threads should be fine for his needs.

Comment: Added an Edit based on your observations. Thank you :)