# What is the relationship between a CPU thread, an OS thread, and a programming language thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, operating-system, multiprocessing

> What is the relationship between a CPU thread, an OS thread, and a programming language thread?

I've been wondering what the relationship between a CPU thread, an OS thread, and programming language thread is?

If a processor has `n` CPU threads (typically equal to the amount of CPU cores), the OS may create `m > n` threads to be scheduled for execution on the CPU threads (please, correct me if I'm wrong).

How are the programming language threads related to the OS threads? When I create a thread in a programming language, is the language then calling into the OS to create a new thread?

Comment: For the OS thread, from Tanenbaum, Modern Operating Systems: In traditional operating systems, each process has an address space and a single
thread of control. In fact, that is almost the definition of a process. Nevertheless,
in many situations, it is desirable to have multiple threads of control in the same
address space running in quasi-parallel, as though they were (almost) separate
processes (except for the shared address space).

Comment: I would recommend reading this book as a whole, as this is a deep rabbit hole, and you might want to get know to operating systems abstractions, like address space, processes, scheaduler, multiprogramming, system calls and so on.

Comment: Simply speaking, a processor thread is physical processor core, however (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) simultaneous multithreading allows the hardware implementation of something like an OS thread.

Comment: I am not a Python-guy but I do know, that using C or C++ you can create new processes using system calls (fancy names for functions for the OS specifically) from appropriate libraries, like `fork()` for creating a new process and `pthread_create() ` to create a new thread, in case of POSIX conformant systems. Windows has the equvivalent calls, found in the Win32 API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/). You might want to check out this question regarding this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810/how-do-i-start-threads-in-plain-c .